# Подсчет времени

Tags: php

Надо посчитать время, работу за день, за месяц, за неделю. Я табель составляю. Как это сделать?

Comment: Что значит посчитать??

Comment: Конкретнее?

Comment: @turebekuly, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$time = microtime(true);// Запоминаем начало скрипта

//some script body

print((microtime(true)-$time));Выводим разницу между началом и концом.
```

Для вялотекущих операций достаточно time().

Answer (score 1):

чего??
ну `time()` например

> Возвращает количество секунд, прошедших с начала Эпохи Unix (The Unix Epoch, 1 января 1970 00:00:00 GMT) до текущего времени.